# How to know when Chromium has stopped making network requests?

Tags: android, html, network-programming, crosswalk-runtime, webviewchromium

We are working with HTML5 games we need to know when a game has completely finished downloading all it's assets. In case of HTML5, this is not the same as when the page finishes loading. After the page finishes loading, the game's assets are downloaded.

We are running these games in a native app in which we have embedded the [Crosswalk](http://crosswalk-project.org) webview. The Crosswalk-project is based on the Chromium project, so chances are what works for Chromium will work for Crosswalk too. How do I find out when the browser has completely stopped making network requests and has basically stopped all communication with the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great addon for Google Chrome called Live Http Headers. It's also available for Firefox.

You can get the addon for Google Chrome [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-http-headers/iaiioopjkcekapmldfgbebdclcnpgnlo?hl=en).

It will capture each request your browser is making and show you the headers and status codes:
[image]

If you are on Linux you can also monitor network usage by application using nethogs but not as detailed as Live Http Headers.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install nethogs
nethogs eth0
```

You could also monitor traffic on port 80:

```
tshark -i eth0 -f "port 80"
```

Alternatively you can use Wireshark instead of the command line version and you can get that [here](https://www.wireshark.org/) it works on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Here is an example filter in Wireshark:
[image]

A more permanent solution as you requested in the comments is to put a device directly in line with your device running the application and use tcpdump:

```
sudo tcpdump -A -s 0 'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'
```

This will show the get, response, and payload and should be plenty information for debugging. Add the `-i` option to specify the interface. A computer to share it's network connection between two network interface cards would work great for this.

Hope this helps.

--lillypad

Comment: Thanks for answering Lillypad. The thing is, we are using the Crosswalk webview within a native Android app, and want this response in code in real time.

While this is great for checking out what files are being fetched, this is manual work and does not have an API available for Android. :/ 

Any other thoughts on what  code we could write to automate processes?

Comment: I've added the more permanent solution for you in the answer above.